# Prove that if there exists $c,M>0$ such that $|a_nc^n|\leq M\forall n$, then $(-c,c)\subseteq\operatorname{Conv}(\sum a_nx^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Prove that if there exists $c,M>0$ such that $|a_nc^n|\leq M\,\forall n$, then $(-c,c)\subseteq \operatorname{Conv}(\sum a_nx^n)$.

I tried to use the ratio test to, but I only get that $c\limsup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\leq 1$ which is useless. I also thougth the root test could be useful, but again I reached nothing.

I'm looking for just a few hints, not complete answers, I only know pretty basic stuff about power series (root/ratio test, limsups/infs and not much more).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any $x \in \mathbb R,$ $a_nx^n = a_nc^n(x^n/c^n).$

Comment: Then you only need to apply the root test right? Nice answer.

Comment: Or just the comparison test: If $ |x|<c,$ then $|a_nx^n| \le M(|x|/c)^n$ and because $|x|/c<1,$ we are comparing to a convergent geometric series.